# Subversion on laptop and moving between internal/external network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ip-address, router

I have a subversion server on my local network and access it using the 192.168.1.x address.  The problem is that when I leave my house and need to update svn on my laptop, I now have to use an external address.  I've been using the svn relocate command to switch between external and internal addresses, but this is cumbersome.  Does anyone have a clever trick around this issue?  I use TortoiseSVN as my client.

A DNS entry on my router would probably work so I could use the external name all the time, but unfortunately my router it isn't that flexible.

Comment: I bet a shiny sixpence you'll get at least one answer telling you to use git

Comment: @Rich - oooh, close - I resisted the temptation, and merely hinted that all the cool kids are using git.  But there's still a good possibility that someone will.

Comment: Have a look at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Maybe some small script to switch a line in there would help? P.S.: Don't use gt, svn is fine `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a record to your hosts file, and then change that instead of relocating.

BTW, what's wrong with always using external name? (besides unnessesary traffic)

Comment: If you are behind a NAT and mapped the SVN server as a virtual host, external name probably won't work.

Comment: I've never been able to get that to work.  Trying to use my external address from inside my network always fails.  I am behind NAT.  IIRC it fails because the router doesn't know what to do with the external address on a LAN->LAN connection.

Comment: That sounds like a router misconfiguration. It should be possible with a modern router to use your external address from inside the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

I always use my external address, and have a bash script that sets up the ssh tunnels I want to get to my repositories.  Was svn, now git, but the same principal applies.